# Joomla: How to create a blog of articles from multiple categories?

Tags: blog, joomla, section

I need to gather articles from multiple categories into the single blog feed (the front page and main RSS feed).

For example, I need this structure ...

```
Section 1
  Category 1.1
    Article 1.1.1 (20 apr 2011)
    Article 1.1.2 (10 apr 2011)
  Category 1.2
    Article 1.2.1 (15 apr 2011)
  Category 1.3
    Article 1.3.1 (25 apr 2011)
```

... to be displayed in a single blog as

```
Article 1.3.1 (25 apr 2011)
Article 1.1.1 (20 apr 2011)
Article 1.2.1 (15 apr 2011)
Article 1.1.2 (10 apr 2011)
```

(sorted by the creation date of articles)

I tried to use "Section Blog" type for my menu item, but I can't understand its methods of sorting articles. I tried to sort them by date, but my section blog displaying it category by category, not article by article:

```
Article 1.1.1 (20 apr 2011)
Article 1.1.2 (10 apr 2011)
Article 1.2.1 (15 apr 2011)
Article 1.3.1 (25 apr 2011)
```

Maybe I should install some extension to do that?

Joomla 1.5.22

Comment: Bounty started, because I want to find a better solution than Zaragoza Content component, because it does not want to post the full article from the frontpage into the main RSS feed. My PHP skills are not enough to fix it. Please help me

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I installed the component Zaragoza Content, and it works with your fix. Only problem is that I cant implement the layout fix as my template does not have the file "\templates[template-name]\html\com_content\category\blog_item.php". I can see that other templates has got it, but my current doesn't. In that directory it only has "blog.php" and default.php. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the required *Articles* can select option `Front Page` to `Yes` and create `Front Page Blog Layout` *Menu Item*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I need. It's good that I haven't used frontpage blog anywhere on my website yet. Interesting, is it possible to use "multi frontpage" view, if I need another blog like this?

Comment: @Andrew What is meant by _"like this"_? For example, if have to show the **same** articles, but in **different** layout - it's available since `1.6`, details are here: [Introduction to Alternative Layout Feature in Version 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6#Introduction_to_Alternative_Layout_Feature_in_Version_1.6)

Answer (score 0):

I have founded an appropriate free Joomla component called [Zaragoza Content](http://goo.gl/lMbZL)

Current implementation for Joomla 1.5 is a little bit buggy, but here is my fix:

1. Install this component into Joomla. After this you can select the main menu item type "Zaragoza Content » Blog" and select IDs of categories you want to display in the single feed.
2. Overwrite the file "\components\com_zaragozacontent\views\blog\tmpl\default_blog_item.php" by the file from your current template, in my case "\templates[template-name]\html\com_content\category\blog_item.php", because it has a bit different presentation.
3. Fix the file \components\com_zaragozacontent\views\blog\view.html.php by adding 2 lines to the top of it (right after the first PHP open brace "?php"):

   JHTML::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'helpers');
   JHTML::addIncludePath(JPATH_BASE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_content'.DS.'helpers');

Answer (score 0):

I know Wordpress provides this possibility and there is a Wordpress blog for Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/blog/6659

Comment: This is really weighty and expensive solution. I hope someone will find something more light-weight.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) lets you join together various RSS feeds.